# Step by step on how to connect to Infusionsoft using OAuth2 using Passport Infusionsoft

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth-2.0, infusionsoft

Hi I tried this module to communicate with Infusionsoft: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-infusionsoft but somehow, when I tried to run it (using the samples on the npm module) by running it [here](https://npm.runkit.com/passport-infusionsoft)  and also on my local node app (same code) nothing happens. Upon reading the documentation: https://developer.infusionsoft.com/authentication/#request-access-token, there are things that are not clear such as:

**Once the user has logged into their Infusionsoft account and authorized your application, they will be redirected back to your application at your specified redirect_uri with a code URL parameter that is used to request an access token. Redirect users to https://signin.infusionsoft.com/app/oauth/authorize along with the required parameters in order to start the OAuth exchange.**

Based on the steps provided by the documentation and the samples of the node module, how can I use them all together? I apologize since I'm not sure of the entire process. The goal is I need to at least get the token from the Infusionsoft after I submit the clientID and clientSecret. What is the difference of the callback and the redirect URL? If there are more understandable samples, please help me..